# Launching vscode from bash gives the following error

Tags: bash

Output of `code --verbose`:

```
[main 3:45:14 PM] Error: listen EACCES /run/user/0/vscode-4369ae7e-1.29.1-main.sock
        at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
        at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
        at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1334:19)
        at listenInCluster (net.js:1392:12)
        at Server.listen (net.js:1487:5)
        at /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:190:282
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at Object.t.serve (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:190:215)
        at n (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:503:143)
        at Q (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:505:411)
        at t.e.invokeFunction (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:220:247)
        at /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:506:361
        at Object.v [as _notify] (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:101:572)
        at Object.enter (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:104:924)
        at n.Class.derive._oncancel._run (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:106:790)
        at n.Class.derive._oncancel._completed (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:106:231)
        at u (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:109:680)
        at V.then.o.(anonymous function) (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:109:894)
        at Object.v [as _notify] (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:101:572)
        at Object.enter (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:104:924)
        at n.Class.derive._oncancel._run (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:106:790)
        at n.Class.derive._oncancel._completed (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:106:231)
        at /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:137:453
        at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (original-fs.js:153:5)
    [main 3:45:14 PM] Lifecycle#kill()
```

Output of `bash -x code`:

```
++ id -u
+ '[' 1000 = 0 ']'
+ '[' '!' -L code ']'
++ dirname code
+ VSCODE_PATH=./..
+ ELECTRON=./../code
+ CLI=./../resources/app/out/cli.js
+ ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1
+ ./../code ./../resources/app/out/cli.js
/usr/bin/code: line 35: ./../code: No such file or directory
+ exit 127
```

Content of `/usr/bin/code`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
# Licensed under the MIT License. See License.txt in the project root for license information.

# If root, ensure that --user-data-dir or --file-write is specified
if [ "$(id -u)" = "0" ]; then
    for i in $@
    do
        if [[ $i == --user-data-dir || $i == --user-data-dir=* || $i == --file-write ]]; then
            CAN_LAUNCH_AS_ROOT=1
        fi
    done
    if [ -z $CAN_LAUNCH_AS_ROOT ]; then
        echo "You are trying to start vscode as a super user which is not recommended. If you really want to, you must specify an alternate user data directory using the --user-data-dir argument." 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi
fi

if [ ! -L $0 ]; then
    # if path is not a symlink, find relatively
    VSCODE_PATH="$(dirname $0)/.."
else
    if which readlink >/dev/null; then
        # if readlink exists, follow the symlink and find relatively
        VSCODE_PATH="$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))/.."
    else
        # else use the standard install location
        VSCODE_PATH="/usr/share/code"
    fi
fi

ELECTRON="$VSCODE_PATH/code"
CLI="$VSCODE_PATH/resources/app/out/cli.js"
ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1 "$ELECTRON" "$CLI" "$@"
exit $?
```

Any suggestions?